# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError (CheckpointedRestoring) when trying to create a Kafka Consumer in Flink

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am trying to create an Kafka Consumer in Apache Flink. I have been following the setup as well as the guide in the Apache Flink docs. But i am getting a *java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/streaming/api/checkpoint/CheckpointedRestoring* error.

The error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/streaming/api/checkpoint/CheckpointedRestoring
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.agt.examples.KafkaConsumer.main(KafkaConsumer.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.checkpoint.CheckpointedRestoring
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 30 more
```

KafkaConsumer.class is

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    // For Apache Kafka Consumer
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");

    DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer08<String>("my-flink-topic", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties));

    stream.map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -6867736771747690202L;

        @Override
        public String map(String value) throws Exception {
            return value;
        }
    }).print();
    env.execute();
```

The pom.xml is

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.8_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The Flink version is 1.4.2, java version is 1.8 and i am using intellij IDEA . I think it must be something related to dependency not linking properly but i am not able to understand what could be the issue here. I checked for the class mentioned above but its not in the streaming/api/checkpoint  in my libraries and when i checked online it seems to be a deprecated class. I tried mvn clean install, Invalidated caches and Restart, Generate sources and update folders but still the same error is popping up. I created the project by following the instructions in the apache flink setup page https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/quickstart/java_api_quickstart.html but some of the other dependencies where added as i was doing the development from different sources. Is it something related to the version for one of the dependencies? I am totally out of my depth here.

Help would be hugely appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have inconsistent versions of `flink-clients_2.10` and `flink-connector-kafka-0.8_2.10` dependencies. Try to use `${flink.version}` instead of `1.2.1` in the following parts:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-clients_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.8_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. Changed it to ${flink.version} for the clients and then i did the same for connector also. The only change for connector was i had to change the artifactId to "flink-connector-kafka-0.8_2.11" after referring to the maven repository. But now it is working like a charm. Again a huge thanks :)